# How to attach letters from an array to create a word

Tags: javascript, arrays, join, split

I have this simple code, the expected outcome that I WANT from console logging the code is `['STAR', 'TIP']`. But I am having issues in achieving my desired `console.log` message. Here is my code

```
const testArr = ['S', 'T', 'A', 'R', '', 'T', 'I', 'P'];

console.log(testArr.join('').split(' '));       //Result is     [ 'STARTIP' ]
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `' '` instead of `''` in your array?

Comment: console.log(testArr.join('').split(''));  
I tried this code on the left and the result is 
[
  'S', 'T', 'A',
  'R', 'T', 'I',
  'P'
]

Comment: No, your array. As in: `['S', 'T', 'A', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'I', 'P'];`

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could first map to update the empty entry to a delimiter like a space, then join and split on the delimiter:

```js
const testArr = ['S', 'T', 'A', 'R', '', 'T', 'I', 'P'];
console.log(testArr.map(s => s === '' ? ' ' : s).join("").split(" "));
```

Or for example using reduce, and start of with an array and an empty string.

```js
const testArr = ['S', 'T', 'A', 'R', '', 'T', 'I', 'P'];
console.log(
  testArr.reduce((a, c) => {
    c !== '' ? a[a.length - 1] += c : a.push("")
    return a;
  }, [""])
);
```